# Find a Binary Data Sequence in a Signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, correlation

### Here's my goal:

I'm trying to find a way to search through a data signal and find (index) locations where a known, repeating binary data sequence is located. Then, because the spreading code and demodulation is known, pull out the corresponding chip of data and read it. Currently, I believe xcorr will do the trick.

### Here's my problem:

I can't seem to interpret my result from xcorr or xcorr2 to give me what I'm looking for. I'm either having a problem cross-referencing from the vector location of my xcorr function to my time vector, or a problem properly identifying my data sequence with xcorr, or both. Other possibilities may exist.

### Where I am at/What I have:

I have created a random BPSK signal that consists of the data sequence of interest and garbage data over a repeating period. I have tried processing it using xcorr, which is where I am stuck.

#### Here's my code:

```
%% Clear Variables

clc;
clear all, close all;

%% Create random data

nbits = 2^10;
ngarbage = 3*nbits;
data = randi([0,1],1,nbits);
garbage = randi([0,1],1,ngarbage);
stream = horzcat(data,garbage); 

%% Convert from Unipolar to Bipolar Encoding

stream_b = 2*stream - 1;

%% Define Parameters

%%% Variable Parameters
nsamples = 20*nbits;
nseq = 5 %# Iterate stream nseq times
T = 10; %# Number of periods
Ts = 1; %# Symbol Duration
Es = Ts/2; %# Energy per Symbol
fc = 1e9; %# Carrier frequency

%%% Dependent Parameters
A = sqrt(2*Es/Ts); %# Amplitude of Carrier
omega = 2*pi*fc %# Frequency in radians
t = linspace(0,T,nsamples) %# Discrete time from 0 to T periods with nsamples samples
nspb = nsamples/length(stream) %# Number of samples per bit

%% Creating the BPSK Modulation
%# First we have to stretch the stream to fit the time vector. We can quickly do this using _
%# simple matrix manipulation.

% Replicate each bit nspb/nseq times
repStream_b = repmat(stream_b',1,nspb/nseq);

% Tranpose and replicate nseq times to be able to fill to t
modSig_proto = repmat(repStream_b',1,nseq);

% Tranpose column by column, then rearrange into a row vector
modSig = modSig_proto(:)';

%% The Carrier Wave

carrier = A*cos(omega*t);

%% Modulated Signal

sig = modSig.*carrier;
```

#### Using XCORR

I use `xcorr2()` to eliminate the zero padding effect of `xcorr` on unequal vectors. See comments below for clarification.

```
corr = abs(xcorr2(data,sig); %# pull the absolute correlation between data and sig
[val,ind] = sort(corr(:),'descend') %# sort the correlation data and assign values and indices
ind_max = ind(1:nseq); %# pull the nseq highest valued indices and send to ind_max
```

Now, I think this should pull the five highest correlations between data and sig. These should correspond to the end bit of data in the stream for every iteration of stream, because I would think that is where the data would most strongly cross-correlate with sig, but they do not. Sometimes the maxes are not even one stream length apart. So I'm confused here.

### Question

In a three part question:

1. Am I missing a certain step? How do I use xcorr in this case to find where data and sig are most strongly correlated?
2. Is my entire method wrong? Should I not be looking for the max correlations?
3. Or should I be attacking this problem from another angle, id est, not use xcorr and maybe use filter or another function?

Comment: wow...pretty long and verbose question..do you think it would be possible to reduce the question to a couple of lines with focus only on the real problem you're facing?

Comment: @fpe I apologize for enabling the -v option ...Well I didn't want to leave anything out. Usually it seems when questions are summarized, a lot of follow on questions are asked. To summarize this question: "How do I use xcorr to find the data stream `data` in the modulated signal `sig`?"

Comment: You still didn't show how you are calculating `xcorr` though ;) Please add that

Comment: @Dan I thought I did. I used the code in the second code block: `corr = abs(xcorr2(data,sig);` then I used a simple sort to pull out the max correlations. Is this what you mean? I just edited my question to better highlight the `xcorr` block.

Comment: oh are you saying `int16(xcorr2) == int16(xcorr(xcorr ~= 0)` is actually `int16(xcorr2(data,sig)) == int16(xcorr(xcorr(data, sig) ~= 0)`?? Because as you have it in your question it looks like you are using `xcorr` as a variable, not a function.

Comment: if you name a variable then apply those functions they are the same (in this instance). So if `corr = xcorr(x,y)` and `corr2 = xcorr2(x,y)` then `int16(corr2) == int16(corr(corr ~= 0);` . I was simply trying to show why I choose the xcorr2 function over xcorr. I apologize if this was confusing, I'll edit the question to clear this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @David K 's and @Patrick Mineault's help I manage to track down where I went wrong. First @Patrick Mineault suggested I flip the signals. The best way to see what you would expect from the result is to slide the small vector along the larger, searched vector. So

```
corr = xcorr2(sig,data);
```

Then I like to chop off the end there because it's just extra. I did this with a trim function I made that simply takes the signal you're sliding and trims it's irrelevant pieces off the end of the xcorr result.

```
trim = @(x,s2) x(1:end - (length(s2) - 1));
trim(corr,data);
```

Then, as @David K suggests, you need to have the data stream you're looking for encoded the same as your searched signal. So in this case

```
data = 2*data-1;
```

Second, if you just have your data at it's original bit length, and not at it's stretched, iterated length, it **can** be found in the signal but it will be VERY noisy. To reduce the noise, simply stretch the data to match it's stretched length in the iterated signal. So

```
rdata = repmat(data',1,nspb/nseq);
rdata = repmat(rdata',1,nseq);
data = rdata(:)';
```

Now finally, we should have crystal clear correlations for this case. And to pull out the maxes that should correspond to those correlations I wrote

```
[sortedValues sortIndex] = sort(corr(:),'descend');
c = 0 ;
for r = 1 : length(sortedValues)
    if sortedValues(r,:) == max(corr)
        c = c + 1;
        maxIndex(1,c) = sortIndex(r,:);
    else break % If you don't do this, you get loop lock
    end
 end
```

Now `c` should end up being `nseq` for this case and you should have 5 index times where the corrs should be! You can easily pull out the bits with another loop and `c` or `length(maxIndex)`. I've also made this into a more "real world" toy script, where there is a data stream, doppler, fading, and it's over a time vector in seconds instead of samples.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Your overall method is great and makes a lot of sense.  The problem you're having is that you're getting some actual correlation with your garbage data.  I noticed that you shifted all of your sream to be zero-centered, but didn't do the same to your data.  If you zero-center the data, your correlation peaks will be better defined (at least that worked when I tried it).

```
data = 2*data -1;
```

Also, I don't recommend using a simple sort to find your peaks.  If you have a wide peak, which is especially possible with a noisy signal, you could have two high points right next to each other.  Find a single maximum, and then zero that point and a few neighbors.  Then just repeat however many times you like. Alternatively, if you know how long your epoch is, only do a correlation with one epoch's worth of data, and iterate through the signal as it arrives.

Comment: In my efforts to solve this myself, I was definitely moving towards the solution you suggested. I did zero-center the data, and it does help. However, as you noted, there is a _lot_ of noise because of the correlation between data and garbage. So I am starting to work on the epoch iteration idea. So far -- break the sig into an array (let's call it epochArray) with length length(sig)/nseq and nseq rows. Then, iteratively seperate the array into rows, so that epoch1 = epochArray(1,:), epoch2 = epochArray(2,:) et cetera while also correlating data to each epochArray row. About right?

Comment: @endowdly: Sounds about right! To simplify things and make it easier for expansion in the future, I recommend simply looping through the signal and having an 'epoch' variable that updates each loop.  This prevents having too many individual epoch variables and a large epochArray.

Comment: Good idea! I'll work through that and see what shakes out. note: I have been able to visually identify the correlations I'm looking for by adding the epoch boundaries to my xcorr2 plot; you can easily see a spike at ~nbits into each epoch. For 2^4 and less nbits, the correlation is exactly where you expect it to be (e.g. at t = 32). Seems my basic idea works perfect for low nbit numbers. So let's see how can make it work for the higher amounts!

Comment: I've also found that it helps if you stretch the data signal to correspond to the length of one iteration. I don't know why I overlooked this. When I finally figure out how to pull the correlations out, I'll post if it works or not. I'm currently trying to do a max average of a "slice" of the correlations based on your max point zeroing advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try flipping the signal, i.e.:

```
corr = abs(xcorr2(data,sig(end:-1:1));
```

Is that any better?

Comment: After checking this out... isn't this identical to `corr = abs(xcorr2(data,fliplr(sig)));` ? I didn't mention this early, but I did try `fliplr` on both data and sig seperately. Didn't seem to improve sorting or finding maxes.

Comment: This does however, help arrange the data to be better visually identified. See my comments on David K's answer.

Comment: actually the best way to see this, where the vectors slide as you would expect (small along big) do `corr = abs(xcorr2(sig,data));`